# In Game Maker, how do I draw a surface?

Tags: rendering, game-maker

I'm trying to draw a surface in black in Game Maker. This is the code:

```
//Create event
surf = surface_create(room_width, room_height);

//Draw event
surface_set_target(surf);
draw_clear_alpha(c_black, 0.8);
surface_reset_target();
```

It seems to only work when I minimize and then maximize the game. How can I make this work without having to minimize the game?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually drawing the surface here. You clear it with black and then leave it.

You need to draw the surface with `draw_surface(surf, x, y)`

Furthermore, you shouldn't clear the surface every draw event if it is not going to change. Move

```
surface_set_target(surf);
draw_clear_alpha(c_black, 0.8);
surface_reset_target();
```

to the create event and the surface will only be cleared once.